# Problema al crear tablas Mysql con PhpMyadmin

Tags: mysqli, phpmyadmin

Buenas tardes,

tengo un problemilla creando tablas con PhpMyadmin mi sentencia es esta:

```
CREATE TABLE `prensacarv1`.`pr_clients` (
    `clientId` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `firstName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    `lastName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    `netProfit` INT(3) NOT NULL,
    `address` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `locality` INT(10) NOT NULL,
    `postalCode` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    `province` INT(10) NOT NULL,
    `country` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `coordinates` POINT NOT NULL,
    `latitude` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    `longitude` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    `email` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    `comment` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `userId` INT(10) NOT NULL,
    `created` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `modified` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `active` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`clientId` (10))
)  ENGINE=INNODB;
```

y al pulsar Guardar me aparece el siguiente mensaje de error:

> #1089 - Incorrect prefix key; the used key part isn't a string, the used length is longer than the key part, or the storage engine doesn support unique prefiex keys

¿Alguien sabe que está ocurriendo?

Comment: Arriba donde declaras las columnas de la tabla le pones al `clientId int not null auto_increment` y abajo en la primaryKey solo pones `clienteid`.

Comment: Es algo tan sencillo: primero crear toda la tabla con las columnas. Luego de crearla, definir la clave primaria. Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me llamó la atención que el error 1089 arrojado presente tres posibles motivos:

> 1089 - Incorrect prefix key;
>
> *(a)* the used key part isn't a string,
>
> *(b)* the used length is longer than the key part,
>
> *(c)* or the storage engine doesn support unique prefiex keys

En tu caso el error se debe al primer motivo: *the used key part isn't a string*, y ocurre porque estás tratando una columna del tipo `INT` como si fuera del tipo `VARCHAR`. El error se corregiría, como se ha dicho en otras respuestas, quitando el tamaño de la columna indicado en la declaración de la `PRIMARY KEY` en esta línea:

Cambiar:

<s>`PRIMARY KEY (clientId (10))`</s>

Por:

```
PRIMARY KEY (`clientId`)
```

### Perooo.

No significa que indicar una longitud a la `PRIMARY KEY` **sea siempre incorrecto**.

En su [documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-index.html) MySQL indica que los prefijos de claves son válidos en columnas de los siguientes tipos: `CHAR, VARCHAR, BINARY, VARBINARY, BLOB y TEXT`.

> Prefixes can be specified for CHAR, VARCHAR, BINARY, and VARBINARY
>   column indexes.
>
> Prefixes must be specified for BLOB and TEXT column indexes.

De hecho, en MYSQL, si la columna de tu tabla que hará las funciones de `PRIMARY KEY` es del tipo `VARCHAR` **puedes indicar perfectamente que quieres sólamente un prefijo de dicha columna como `PRIMARY KEY`**, es decir los `n` caracteres indicados entre paréntesis a partir de la izquierda.

Así que una sentencia como esta es totalmente correcta:

```
CREATE TABLE `prensacarv1`.`pr_clients` (
    `clientId` INT(10) NOT NULL,
    `firstName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    `lastName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    -- otras columnas ...,
    PRIMARY KEY (`firstName` (10))
)  ENGINE=INNODB;
```

en ella indicamos que la `PRIMARY KEY` serán los primeros 10 caracteres del nombre de la persona.

En cambio, si haces esto:

```
CREATE TABLE `prensacarv1`.`pr_clients` (
    `clientId` INT(10) NOT NULL,
    `firstName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    `lastName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    -- otras columnas ...,
    PRIMARY KEY (`firstName` (999))
)  ENGINE=INNODB;
```

estarías cometiendo la parte (b) del mensaje de error: *the used length is longer than the key part*, ya que le estás indicando que tome 999 caracteres cuando la longitud de la columna es de sólo 45.

Para más información sobre el **interesante error  1089** se puede consultar [el siguiente artículo](http://www.mysqlab.net/knowledge/kb/detail/topic/error%20messages/id/6576).

Comment: Muy buena respuesta, muchas gracias. Solucioné el error aunque debo de añadir que también fallaba el tipo de datos POINT para las coordenadas. Tuve que crear la tabla y posteriormente añadir el campo coordinates manualmente. De nuevo Muchas gracias

Answer (score 2):

Con:

```
PRIMARY KEY (clientId(10))
```

le estas indicando la longitud a la *primary Key* y no deberías. Solo debes usar:

```
PRIMARY KEY (clientId)
```

sin indicarle el length, eso debería funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

La **Primary Key** ya definiste el largo arriba. Abajo solo le estas colocando la propiedad de llave primaria, no debe nuevamente definirse el largo de este.

```
`clientId` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```

Allí definiste el largo 10 como tipo INT

```
PRIMARY KEY (`clientId` (10))
```

y alli debes solo definir cual de todas las columnas creadas la dejaras como llave primaria, no volver a definir.

Saludos y éxito.